# What is the purpose of spring cloud stream instanceCount?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-stream

In Spring cloud stream, what exactly is the usage of that property `spring.cloud.stream.instanceCount`?

I mean if that value become wrong because at a moment one or more micro services instances are down, how could this affect the behavior of our infrastructure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`instanceCount` is used to partition data across different consumers. Having one or more services down should not really impact your producers, that's the job of the broker.

So let's say you have a source that sends data to 3 partitions, so you'd have instanceCount=3 and each instance would have it's own partition assigned via `instanceIndex`.

Each instance would be consuming data, but if instance 2 crashes, 0,1 would still be reading data from the partitions, and source would still be sending data as usual.

Assuming your platform has some sort of recoverability in place, your crashed instance should come back to life and resume it's operations.

What we still don't support is dynamic allocation of partitions on runtime, we are investigating this as a story for a future release.

Comment: Note that this only applies to binders that don't naturally support partitioning; with Kafka, the partitions will be rebalanced across the remaining instances. With RabbitMQ, for example, there is a queue per partition so messages will accumulate in the dead instance's queue until it's restarted. The instance count is used as a modulo when calculating the partition number with any binder.

Comment: @GaryRussell So does this mean, if we are using Kafka, will this property be ignored?

Comment: With Kafka, the `instanceCount` is only used `a)` to determine how many partitions to provision (`instanceCouint * concurrency`) and `b)` to distribute the partitions across instances when group management is not being used (`autoRebalanceEnabled=false`).